# Math Calculus in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have several calculus to do in my ruby app.
My code is currently working but I find it very ugly.

```
@guestreviews = GuestReview.where(:reviewed_id => @user.id)
@hostreviews = HostReview.where(:reviewed_id => @user.id)
@hospitalityrate = 0
@foodrate = 0
@placerate = 0
@hostreviews.try(:each) do | rate |
  @hospitalityrate += rate.people_rate
  @foodrate += rate.food_rate
  @placerate += rate.place_rate
end
@hospitalityrate = (@hospitalityrate / @hostreviews.size).round
@foodrate = (@foodrate / @hostreviews.size).round
@placerate = (@placerate / @hostreviews.size).round
@averagerate = ((@hospitalityrate + @foodrate + @placerate) / @hostreviews.size).round
```

Any idea how to make it still readable but less ugly ?

Comment: why are all of these instance variables? why not use some local variables?

Comment: You're misusing `try`. `@hostreviews` is guaranteed to be an array of 0 or more items, it *will* respond to `each`. Don't use `try` here.

Comment: @meagar I don't use try anymore, but hostreviews can also be nil.

Comment: @bl0b No, it can't be `nil`. `where` will always return a chainable scope which responds to `each`, which will behave like an array of 0 or more elements. In the code you've posted, it's impossible for `@hostreviews` to be `nil` by the time it reaches the `each` statement.

Comment: @meagar You're right. I juste checked my code and I don't use the .each anymore and it wasn't nil but an empty array.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually easier to do this in the database layer. It's exceedingly good at these kinds of things.

```
@guest_reviews = GuestReview.where(:reviewed_id => @user.id)
@host_reviews  = HostReview.where(:reviewed_id => @user.id)

@hospitality_rate = @guest_reviews.average('people_rate')
@food_rate        = @guest_reviews.average('food_rate')
@place_rate       = @guest_reviews.average('place_rate')

@average_rate = [@hospitality_rate, @food_rate, @place_rate].inject(:+).to_f / @host_reviews.count
```

It'll result in more database queries, but overall it's more efficient.

I've left out the `round()` call on the `@average_rate` only because that seems like a presentation concern to me. Let the controller figure out the average (decimals and all), and let the view decide how to round and display it.

You could also add a `has_many :guest_reviews, :foreign_key => "reviewed_id"` to the `User` model, so you can just call `@user.guest_reviews.average(...)`. Same for `host_reviews`

If you do that, you could also consider simply moving the calculations to the `User` model, so you don't need to do it all in the controller. And perhaps you could cache the results on the user record and only recalculate when reviews are added/deleted/changed. Assuming this happens less often than the averages being displayed, it'll speed up things a bit.

Lastly, (and this is just small stuff) I'd probably rename some of the variables. I.e. call it `@food_rate_average` instead of `@food_rate` in order to a) indicate that it's an average, and b) so it's not confused with the database column of the same name.
Similarly, I'd call the first average `people_rate_average` rather than `hospitality_rate`; the column is called `people_rate` so it's probably best to keep it consistent with that name (or rename the database column, if "hospitality" is a more fitting name)

*(Edit: Actually, it's more natural to prefix the `average_` rather than suffixing it, i.e. `average_food_rate`, `average_rate`, etc.)*

In the code above, I've also underscored the names, just to keep things consistent with general Rails/Ruby conventions (`FooBar` → `foo_bar`).

---

Edit: Just for fun, you could go fully meta (though it's probably more confusing than anything - the above is much more readable)

```
@guest_reviews = GuestReview.where(:reviewed_id => @user.id)
@host_reviews  = HostReview.where(:reviewed_id => @user.id)

@average_rate = %w(people_rate food_rate place_rate).map { |column|
  instance_variable_set(:"@average_#{column}", @guest_reviews.average(column))
}.inject(:+).to_f / @host_reviews.count
```

That'll set `@average_people_rate`, `@average_food_rate` and so on

Comment: I would give 1000 upvote if I could. That's such a good answer !

Comment: @bl0b Thanks. I had added a few more notes here and there if you're interested

Comment: Thanks. I was actually using the foreign key system, no idea why I wasn't using it. Thanks for the reminder.

Also, I won't cache the result right now because we don't have enough user/visitor yet to worry about it(sadly) but I'll keep it in mind.
I'll change my variables name, you're right it makes more sense with the way you said it.